# Characterization of analytic functions proof

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently reading Elias stein-complex analysis. My Multi-variable analysis isn't very strong, so I just want to know where do we get the formulas for $u(x + h_1,y + h_2) - u(x,y)$ and $v(x + h_1,y + h_2) - v(x,y)$ why are they equal to that partials in that way.

Can somebody explain that part ? That would be excellent.[image]?

Comment: Do you know what the definition of continuosly differentiable is? (in multivariable calculus)

Comment: Yes, the linear map exist and satisfy relation of the limit being 0 when evaluated in some expression

Comment: @JoaquinSan can you explain what is happening?

Comment: Yes, it is the linearization by the total derivative. It is usually the first things you study after you learn the definition of being continuously differentiable; that's why I asked.

Comment: Can you point me to some reference for this ?

Comment: Taylor's theorem for multivariable functions.

Comment: almost any book on multivar calc, e.g. stewart's chapter 3